# Laravel - Get records between two dates from second table

Tags: laravel, date, eloquent

I have something like this:

Table 1: Training Name, created_at, user_id (Plan_Treninga)

Table 2: user_id, created_at, expire_at (InvoiceUser)

I want to pull all from Table 1 where created_at is between Table 2 created_at and expire_at.

This is something what i am trying to..

```
$plan = Plan_Treninga::whereBetween(function($q) use ($id){
          $inv = InvoiceUser::where([
            ["user_id",$id],
            ["status","paid"],
          ])->latest("id")->first();
        })
```

I haven't finished it yet, but my brain stopped working so I have to ask here.

Comment: Is table 1 and 2 linked with each other ?

Comment: No..

The main idea is to get all "Training Plans" created in period of his package duration.

Also, invoiceuser will have more records and i want to have something like this:

Invoice 1# ( ex. 24.05.2020 - 25.05 2020 - this date is from Invoice)
26 training plans - this is from Plan_Treninga

Invocie 2# ( ex. 25.05.2020 - 25.06-2020 )
20 training plans.

Also i want to group it.

Comment: Where exactly are you using `created_at` or `expire_at` in that query?

Comment: Nowhere, i started and didn't finish it. Its fixed, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want clearly is. you want to query all from table 1 which created exist between table 2 created and expire_at right? if so you can use where exist query to achieve this.

```
// assume your table name is plan_treningas & invoice_users
Plan_Treninga::whereExists(function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
          ->from('invoice_users')
          ->whereRaw('plan_treningas.created_at BETWEEN invoice_users.created_at AND invoice_users.expire_at'); // add more query depend your logic
})->get();
```

for more you can take a look at [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-exists-clauses)

or if you want to use raw query

```
SELECT
*
FROM plan_treningas
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM invoice_users WHERE plan_treningas.created_at BETWEEN invoice_users.created_at AND invoice_users.expire_at
)
```

Comment: `$plan = Plan_Treninga::select("name","id","user_id")->where([["user_id",$id],["trainer_id",$user->id]])->whereExists(function ($query) {
               $query->select("name")
                     ->from('invoice_user')
                     ->whereRaw('plan_treninga.created_at BETWEEN invoice_user.created_at AND invoice_user.expire_at'); // add more query depend your logic
            })->get();`

Little modification and its working. God bless you!

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev great it can help you

Comment: how can I group them as invoice_user.id?

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev did this 2 table relate to each other?

Comment: Nope, they aren't.

Comment: oh I just see both table have user_id? did the user_id use for notice which record belong the user right

Comment: Yes, same user_id and also it needs trainer_id to be the same.

Comment: and you want to group by invoice_user.id ?

Comment: if posible can you show me what data you want to archeive

Comment: Well yes. this is invoice_user: https://prnt.sc/sq15wp and this is Plan_Treninga: https://prnt.sc/sq165i

I need all Plan_Treninga which is between Invoice_user (latest one of user and status must be paid) created_at and expire_at. So the solution above won't work if i have more invoices..

Comment: oh you can use join for this. because you have user_id and trainer_id

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding in Plan_Treninga invoice_id and make releationship between them. It will be much easier to pull the data.

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev that right. so it easy to perform join query

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at joins https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins

I am not saying this is the exact solution but I have something similar that I have changed to point you in the right direction.

With joins you can do lots of things.

```
$results = DB::table('table1')
            ->join('table2', function ($join) {
                $join->on('table1.user_id', '=', 'table2.user_id')
                    ->where('table2.status', '=', 'paid')
                    ->where('table2.created_at', '>', 'table1.created_at');
            })
            ->get();
```

Also look at relationships. There is some good answers for setting up many to many relationships.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Answer up fixed my problem. Thanks for solution anyways! I am using Laravel 5.8, is it complicated and painful if i upgrade it to laravel 7?

Comment: Hi glad I could help. I am not sure about upgrading as I started on this version. Upgrading sounds painful, perhaps set up a new setup as a micro service?